# Bootstrap Carousel Borders problems

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i got some Problems with inserting the bootstrap carousel into a webpage... i want to have the picture in fullsize without boarders on the top and bottom... i took a screenshot:

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGAAp.png)

my css code ist this:

```
/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
margin-bottom: 0px;

}

}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
z-index: 5;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
height: 400px;
background-color:#555;
}
.carousel img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-height: 400px;
}

/* Bump up size of carousel content */
.carousel-caption p {
margin-bottom: 20px;
font-size: 21px;
line-height: 1.4;
}
```

and for the container and row tag:

```
.row {
margin-left: -20px;
margin-right: -20px;
}

.container {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: can you fiddle here

Comment: it looks like a box-shadow not borders. Providing code would be helpful

Comment: thank you nikhil :) it was the box-shadow...